# Flowable Enterprise trial version

Tags: flowable

I am trying to start a Flowable Enterprise trial engine, but getting the below exception while starting the `Tomcat` server. I have changed the tomcat port to 8181 instead of 8080 since port 8080 is used by some other service. The server starts perfectly but at the end gives the below exception as a result although the homepage gets loaded but when you click on Flowable engage button the following url gets called `http://localhost:8181/flowable-engage/` and status 404 error is received stating that the requested resource is not available.

```
2021-06-15 00:16:58.427 WARN 23320 — [ main] c.f.l.BaseLicenseCheckService : No Flowable license found in database
2021-06-15 00:19:34.804 WARN 23320 — [able-scheduled-] c.f.l.BaseLicenseCheckService : Error occurred while getting license info

com.flowable.license.exception.FlowableLicenseServiceNotInitializedException: Could not fetch license from database

2021-06-15 00:19:39.574 ERROR 23320 — [ main] o.s.b.SpringApplication : Application run failed

org.flowable.common.engine.api.FlowableException: Could not create index with name plan-items-20210614-1849-07-67747727 and alias plan-items. One possible reason could be that ES is not accessible. See root cause
at com.flowable.indexing.ElasticsearchClientImpl.createIndex(ElasticsearchClientImpl.java:162) ~[flowable-platform-indexing-3.9.2.jar:3.9.2]
at com.flowable.indexing.IndexManagerImpl.createIndexAndAlias(IndexManagerImpl.java:421) ~[flowable-platform-indexing-3.9.2.jar:3.9.2]
at com.flowable.indexing.IndexManagerImpl.createIndexesFromMappings(IndexManagerImpl.java:661) ~[flowable-platform-indexing-3.9.2.jar:3.9.2]
at com.flowable.indexing.IndexManagerImpl.createIndexesAndCustomAliasesFromMappings(IndexManagerImpl.java:524) ~[flowable-platform-indexing-3.9.2.jar:3.9.2]
at com.flowable.indexing.IndexManagerImpl.onApplicationEvent(IndexManagerImpl.java:504) ~[flowable-platform-indexing-3.9.2.jar:3.9.2]
at com.flowable.indexing.IndexManagerImpl.onApplicationEvent(IndexManagerImpl.java:43) ~[flowable-platform-indexing-3.9.2.jar:3.9.2]
at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.doInvokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:176) ~[spring-context-5.3.7.jar:5.3.7]
at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.invokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:169) ~[spring-context-5.3.7.jar:5.3.7]
at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:143) ~[spring-context-5.3.7.jar:5.3.7]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:421) ~[spring-context-5.3.7.jar:5.3.7]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:378) ~[spring-context-5.3.7.jar:5.3.7]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishRefresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:938) ~[spring-context-5.3.7.jar:5.3.7]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:586) ~[spring-context-5.3.7.jar:5.3.7]
at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:144) ~[spring-boot-2.4.6.jar:2.4.6]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:771) ~[spring-boot-2.4.6.jar:2.4.6]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:763) [spring-boot-2.4.6.jar:2.4.6]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:438) [spring-boot-2.4.6.jar:2.4.6]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:339) [spring-boot-2.4.6.jar:2.4.6]
at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.run(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:173) [spring-boot-2.4.6.jar:2.4.6]
at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.createRootApplicationContext(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:153) [spring-boot-2.4.6.jar:2.4.6]
at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.onStartup(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:95) [spring-boot-2.4.6.jar:2.4.6]
at org.springframework.web.SpringServletContainerInitializer.onStartup(SpringServletContainerInitializer.java:174) [spring-web-5.3.7.jar:5.3.7]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5161) [catalina.jar:9.0.46]
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) [catalina.jar:9.0.46]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:717) [catalina.jar:9.0.46]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:690) [catalina.jar:9.0.46]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:692) [catalina.jar:9.0.46]
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:1023) [catalina.jar:9.0.46]
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1903) [catalina.jar:9.0.46]
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511) [?:1.8.0_241]
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) [?:1.8.0_241]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75) [tomcat-util.jar:9.0.46]
at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:112) [?:1.8.0_241]
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWARs(HostConfig.java:824) [catalina.jar:9.0.46]
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:474) [catalina.jar:9.0.46]
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.start(HostConfig.java:1611) [catalina.jar:9.0.46]
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.lifecycleEvent(HostConfig.java:319) [catalina.jar:9.0.46]
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:123) [catalina.jar:9.0.46]
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setStateInternal(LifecycleBase.java:423) [catalina.jar:9.0.46]
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setState(LifecycleBase.java:366) [catalina.jar:9.0.46]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:936) [catalina.jar:9.0.46]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:829) [catalina.jar:9.0.46]
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) [catalina.jar:9.0.46]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1384) [catalina.jar:9.0.46]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1374) [catalina.jar:9.0.46]
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) [?:1.8.0_241]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75) [tomcat-util.jar:9.0.46]
at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:134) [?:1.8.0_241]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:909) [catalina.jar:9.0.46]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:262) [catalina.jar:9.0.46]
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) [catalina.jar:9.0.46]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:433) [catalina.jar:9.0.46]
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) [catalina.jar:9.0.46]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:930) [catalina.jar:9.0.46]
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) [catalina.jar:9.0.46]
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:772) [catalina.jar:9.0.46]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_241]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:1.8.0_241]
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:1.8.0_241]
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[?:1.8.0_241]
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:342) [bootstrap.jar:9.0.46]
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:473) [bootstrap.jar:9.0.46]
Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: 30,000 milliseconds timeout on connection http-outgoing-0 [ACTIVE]
at org.elasticsearch.client.RestClient.extractAndWrapCause(RestClient.java:834) ~[elasticsearch-rest-client-7.9.3.jar:7.9.3]
at org.elasticsearch.client.RestClient.performRequest(RestClient.java:259) ~[elasticsearch-rest-client-7.9.3.jar:7.9.3]
at org.elasticsearch.client.RestClient.performRequest(RestClient.java:246) ~[elasticsearch-rest-client-7.9.3.jar:7.9.3]
at com.flowable.indexing.ElasticsearchClientImpl.createIndex(ElasticsearchClientImpl.java:152) ~[flowable-platform-indexing-3.9.2.jar:3.9.2]
… 61 more
Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: 30,000 milliseconds timeout on connection http-outgoing-0 [ACTIVE]
at org.apache.http.nio.protocol.HttpAsyncRequestExecutor.timeout(HttpAsyncRequestExecutor.java:387) ~[httpcore-nio-4.4.14.jar:4.4.14]
at org.apache.http.impl.nio.client.InternalIODispatch.onTimeout(InternalIODispatch.java:92) ~[httpasyncclient-4.1.4.jar:4.1.4]
at org.apache.http.impl.nio.client.InternalIODispatch.onTimeout(InternalIODispatch.java:39) ~[httpasyncclient-4.1.4.jar:4.1.4]
at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractIODispatch.timeout(AbstractIODispatch.java:175) ~[httpcore-nio-4.4.14.jar:4.4.14]
at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.BaseIOReactor.sessionTimedOut(BaseIOReactor.java:261) ~[httpcore-nio-4.4.14.jar:4.4.14]
at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractIOReactor.timeoutCheck(AbstractIOReactor.java:502) ~[httpcore-nio-4.4.14.jar:4.4.14]
at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.BaseIOReactor.validate(BaseIOReactor.java:211) ~[httpcore-nio-4.4.14.jar:4.4.14]
at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractIOReactor.execute(AbstractIOReactor.java:280) ~[httpcore-nio-4.4.14.jar:4.4.14]
at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.BaseIOReactor.execute(BaseIOReactor.java:104) ~[httpcore-nio-4.4.14.jar:4.4.14]
at
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason why your application is not booting up is because you do not have Elasticsearch running.

The Flowable trial has scripts that can be used to start all the needed components for it. If you are not using those scripts then you have to manually start Elasticsearch and ActiveMQ.

Answer (score 0):

I am using the defaults scripts to start the servers. I am just going to the below path on my machine
D:\Flowable\flowable-engage-3.9.2\flowable\bin

and running the start-engage.bat file

Is there a possibility that i need to change my ports to 8181 at any other place also other than server.xml in folder D:\Flowable\flowable-engage-3.9.2\flowable\tomcat\conf\server.xml

<Connector port="8181" compression="on" protocol="HTTP/1.1"

connection
Timeout="20000"

redirect
Port="8443" />

Please suggest.